# NHibernate with MVC 2 Deployment issue

Tags: nhibernate, iis, asp.net-mvc-2

I am deploying Asp.Net MVC 2 application on Windows Server 2003.
I am using NHibernate for data access.

When I deployed this application on Windows server 2003 and browse to it the application throws an exception saying "hibernate.cfg.xml not found under Windows/System32/inetsrv."

Why NHibernate is searching Windows/System32/inetsrv rather than loading "hibernate.cfg.xml" from the bin folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your app is looking for the file in the webapp root.

When nhibernate loads your config file you need to set the path to config file with Server.MapPath(@"~/bin/nhibernate.cfg.xml").

Comment: Hi All,
I tried doing Server.MapPath(@"bin\nhibernate.cfg.xml")
it is not giving any problem for my Root path but when i change page it is throwing error 
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
Message=Could not find a part of the path 'E:\Applications \source\UserInterface\Accounts\bin\hibernate.cfg.xml'.

I dont know why is the accounts folder here. Why it is searching in Accounts folder i dont have any Accounts folder.

Please help

Comment: Your app most likely has an accounts controller and its trying to access your Accounts views for some reason. Is the controller loading the nhibernate config file?

Comment: Yes. I am having accounts controller and i was trying to access Accounts View.
I am loading the nhibernate config file Session method and giving call to this methd from Controller.
Thanks

Comment: Ok, try changing the config file path to ~/bin/nhibernate.cfg.xml.